# A question about finite groups (a weak version of the converse of Lagrange theorem)

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group of order $n$ and $d$ a positive divisor of $n$. Is it true that
there exists a subgroup of $G$ with order $d$ **or** $n/d$?

Of course this does not hold in full generality. -- In particular one quickly finds that e.g.
${\rm PSL}(2,8)$, ${\rm PSL}(2,11)$, ${\rm PSL}(2,13)$, ${\rm SL}(2,11)$, ${\rm SL}(2,13)$,
${\rm PSL}(2,17)$, ${\rm A}_7$, ${\rm PSL}(2,19)$, ${\rm A}_5 \times {\rm A}_5$, etc.
are counterexamples.

Though does the assertion hold for

- solvable groups?
- solvable groups with derived length less than a certain bound $> 2$?
- groups whose order has at most 2 distinct prime divisors?

A quick computation with [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) shows that any counterexample must have order $\geq 192$.

Comment: This site is meant for questions about research level mathematics, while math.stackexchange.com welcomes mathematical questions at all levels. We have recently been getting a lot of questions that are off-topic here but would have been on-topic at MSE. Could you tell us a bit about what made you select this site to post your question on, as that might help us determine how better to make sure people find the correct site in the first attempt?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: This is much simpler. The OP got this problem as a homework in his/her algebra class. He/she decided to post it here instead of doing the problem on his/her own. Since we do not know OP's home University and the name of the instructor, we cannot send a formal complain. So the OP is safe.

Comment: @MarkSapir Sure, but I would still prefer to get those questions on MSE (where they are closer to being on topic) than being noise here. On the other hand, getting asked here at least means they won't get a full solution handed to them (or at least it is very unlikely).

Comment: OK you two, how quickly can you think of a counterexample!!!!

Comment: @DerekHolt I found one before writing the first comment. It took me a few tries to find it (actually, 2 tries), but it might not be the simplest one.

Comment: @DerekHolt: You must be joking.

Comment: @MarkSapir: While I agree with you that homework questions are off-topic on MO and should be removed, I think your tone is unnecessarily rude. Also, we don't know whether the question is actually the OP's homework. I have therefore chosen to try to improve the question.

Comment: I do not think the problem is a homework question as I have not seen it in any famous undergraduate algebra textbook that I am familiar with.

Comment: @StefanKohl: the smallest counterexample is $AGL(1,16)$ of order $240$.

Comment: @MichaelZieve: O.k., so this leaves only the third part (on groups whose order has only 2 distinct prime divisors).

Comment: While Mark Sapir may have been a little rude, the fact remains that this question is not suitable for MO (it is suitable for MSE), and continuing to discuss it, attempting to improve it, etc, is just encouraging the abuse of this site. If the overall level of questions on MO keeps going down, then the experts who contribute to the discussions will start abandoning the site.

Comment: The revised question is perfectly suitable for math.SE, despite what anyone else here has said.

Comment: @Mark Sapir : Are we in a tribunal? if so, this would not be very encouraging for doing mathematics.  We may lose many young students, who can do great things.  Encouraging people is better than judging theme.