# Factorization of a finite group by two subsets

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I  want to write a GAP program for checking  the following question.

Let $G$ be a given  finite group  with order $n$. Is it true that for every factorization $n=ab$ there exist subsets $A$ and $B$  such that $|A|=a$, $|B|=b$ and $G=AB$?

We have many candidates for a counterexample such as  $PSL(2,8)$, $PSL(2,11)$, $PSL(2,13)$, $SL(2,11)$, $SL(2,13)$, $PSL(2,17)$ and $PSL(2,19)$, and need to check them.

About $PSL_2(8)$, if it has a subgroup of index $21$ with the property (in the above question), then we can say that the answer for $PSL_2(8)$ is positive. Can some body
check it by GAP?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Now, can any one write a GAP code for  $G=PSL_2(8)$, $a=21$ and $b=24$?
(i.e. Are there subsets $A$ and $B$ such that $|A|=21$, $|B|=24$ and $PSL_2(8)=AB$?
or equivalently, are there subsets $A$,  $B$ of $PSL_2(8)$ such that $|A|=21$, $|B|=24$ 
and $|A^{-1}A\cap BB^{-1}|=1$?)

Considering the answer from Peter Mueller, we need to **try some other cases** for getting a counterexample. With do attention to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885778/subgroups-of-groups-of-order-36 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882859/groups-of-order-n2-that-have-no-subgroup-of-order-n?lq=1 , I propose the following groups:

Groups of order $n=m^2$ with no subgroup of order $m$ (so $|G|=mm, a=b=m$). As one can see in the second link $n\geq 24^2$ ($m\geq 24$).

Now, is it true for every group $G$ of order $n=24^2$ and $a=b=24$? What about $n=28^2$,
$n=30^2$, etc.?

Comment: I notice that $A,B$ are described as "subsets", suggesting that you will not require them to be *subgroups* of $G$.

Comment: I think there is more to this exercise than just writing a simple GAP program. For example ${\rm PSL}(2,8)$ has order $504$ and has about $1.86 \times 10^{150}$ subsets of size $252$.

Comment: @hardmath: if you replace "subset" with "subgroup" then the statement is certainly false: consider $Q_8$ for example.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Sure, and I'd started by gathering up links to old "converse Lagrange theorem" posts, until I spotted the wording.

Comment: About $PSL_2(8)$, if it has a subgroup of indexe $21$ with the property (mintioned in the question), then we can say the answer is positive for $PSL_2(8)$. Can any one check it by GAP?

Comment: I think if one of the subsets is a subgroup, even if not a normal subgroup, then you can choose (say) left coset representatives to form the other subset.  So that would be an easy case to settle.

Comment: ${\rm PSL}(2,8)$ has no subgroups of index $21$ and none of index $24$.

Comment: Here is a one-liner in GAP that shows no subgroups of index 21 in $PSL_2(8)$: `G:=PSL(2,8);ForAny(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(G),c->Index(G,Representative(c))=21);`. Same for index 24.

Comment: In case it's relevant, $|AB|=|A||B|$ iff $A^{-1}A$ and $BB^{-1}$ are disjoint.

Comment: You are right, as you can see in the paper: "Upper and lower periodic subsets of semigroups". Indeed the product of subsets $A,B$ is direct iff  $A^{−1}A\cap BB^{-1}=\{ 1\}$.

Comment: `NrCombinations([1..Size(PSL(2,8))],21);` will tell you that the straightforward enumeration of all subsets of orders 21 and 24 is not going to work.

Comment: If you think that such subsets exist, perhaps you could find them with some random search. But if you think that the group is a candidate for the counterexample, it won't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are subsets $A$ and $B$ of orders $21$ and $24$ of $G=PSL(2,8)$ with $G=AB$. A naive search of course does not work. However, in trying to find first $A$ with $A^{-1}A$ being small, a good candidate to work with is $A=G_7G_3$, where $G_3$ and $G_7$ are subgroups of order $3$ and $7$. The smallest possible size of such a set $A^{-1}A$ is $48$. Finding $B$ with $AB=G$ is an exact cover problem: For each $g\in G$ set $S_g=\{ag\;|\;a\in A\}$. Then a set $B$ has the required property if and only if the sets $S_b$, $b\in B$, yield a disjoint union of $G$.

I can't offer a GAP code, rather a quick and naive Sage code which finds such good sets $A$ and $B$:

```
g = PSL(2,8)
n = g.order()
l = {i:x for i,x in enumerate(g)}
li = {y:x for x,y in l.items()}
g7 = g.sylow_subgroup(7)
s3 = g.subgroup([[z for z in g.conjugacy_classes_representatives()\
                  if z.order() == 3][0]])
n3 = g.normalizer(s3)
tv = [z[0] for z in g.cosets(n3)]
for g3 in [s3.conjugate(z) for z in tv]:
    A = [g(zz)*g(z) for zz in g7 for z in g3]
    AA = set([z1^(-1)*z2 for z1 in A for z2 in A])
    print len(AA)
    if len(AA) > 48:
        continue
    M = matrix(n,n,0)
    for i, x in l.items():
        for j in [li[a*x] for a in A]:
            M[i,j] = 1
    c = sage.combinat.matrices.dlxcpp.OneExactCover(M)
    if c == None:
        continue
    B = [[l[i] for i in range(n) if M[i] == row][0] for row in c]
    AB = set([a*b for a in A for b in B])
    print len(AB) == n # Check if AB = G
    break
```

One solution we get is $A=G_7G_3$ with $G_7$ and $G_3$ generated by $(3,8,6,4,9,7,5)$ and $(1,3,4)(2,7,8)(5,9,6)$, and $B=\{(),
 (1,2,4,3,5,6,7,9,8),
 (2,5,8,3,7,6,4),
 (1,2,5,7,3,6,8),
 (2,6,9,4,8,7,5),
 (1,2,7,8,6,4,5),
 (2,8)(3,7)(4,9)(5,6),
 (1,6,5,2,4,8,9,3,7),
 (1,4,6)(2,5,7)(3,8,9),
 (1,5,7,4,6,2,3,9,8),
 (2,7,6,3,4,9,5),
 (2,4)(3,6)(5,7)(8,9),
 (1,5)(3,6)(4,9)(7,8),
 (1,4,8,5,2,3,9,7,6),
 (2,9,5,7,4,3,8),
 (1,7)(2,5)(3,8)(4,9),
 (1,5,8,2,4,6,3,7,9),
 (2,3)(4,6)(5,9)(7,8),
 (1,2,6,8,4,7,9),
 (1,4,5,6,2,9,7,3,8),
 (1,4,8,6,9,3,5),
 (1,3,7,8,5,2,6,4,9),
 (1,2)(3,5)(6,9)(7,8),
 (1,3,9,8,2,4,7)\}$.

**Added:** (in view of the modification of the question) The groups of orders $24^2$ and $28^2$ are solvable by Burnside's $p^aq^b$-Theorem. Hence they don't give counterexamples, as pointed out in the answers to [this related question by the OP](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155986/factor-subset-of-finite-group). These answers, by the way, give more promising indications where possible counterexamples may reside. (As to $PSL(2,8)$, the two potential candidates $(a,b)=(21,24)$ and $(a,b)=(12,42)$ are given there. The first doesn't exist by the result from above, and a slight modification of the above code gives $G=AB$ with $|A|=12$, $|B|=42$, so the other one doesn't exist either.)