# Is each finite group multifactorizable?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, additive-combinatorics

> **Definition.** A finite group $G$ is called *multifactorizable* if for any positive integer numbers $a_1,\dots,a_n$ with $a_1\cdots a_n=|G|$ there are subsets $A_1,\dots,A_n\subset G$ such that $A_1\cdots A_n=G$ and $|A_i|=a_i$ for all $i\le n$.
>
> In this case we shall write that the group $G$ is *$a_1{\times}\cdots{\times}a_n$-factorizable.*

It can be shown that each finite Abelian group is multifactorizable.

> **Problem 1.** Is each finite (simple) group multifactorizable?

As was observed by Geoff Robinson in his answer to this question, each finite nilpotent group is multifactorizable.

> **Problem 2.** Is each finite solvable group multifactorizable?

**Added in Edit.** It turns out that the alternating (solvable) group $A_4$ is not multifactorizable, more precisely, $A_4$ is not $2{\times}3{\times}2$-factorizable.

Now it remains to find an example of a finite simple group which is not multifactorizable.

> **Problem 3.** Is the alternating group $A_5$ multifactorizable? In particular, is $A_5$ $2{\times}15{\times}2$-factorizable?

---

**Added in Edit 2.** By computer calculations, @Fracois Brunault proved that the alternating group $A_5$ is not multifactorizable. More precisely, the group $A_5$ is not $2{\times}3{\times}5{\times}2$-factorizable.

**Added in Edit 3.**
On the other hand, as was remarked by @Gro-Tsen, it is an open problem (of minimal logarithmic signature) if any finite (simple) group $G$ can be written as the product $G=A_1\cdots A_n$ of subsets $A_i\subset G$ whose cardinality $|A_i|$ is a prime number or 4 such that $|G|=|A_1|\cdots|A_n|$. This problem is resolved for some classes of finite simple groups, see [this paper](http://mcccc.sites.unlv.edu/22/Abstract-Singhi1.pdf) for more information.

Comment: You might find it useful to consider the p-group version of this problem.  Gerhard "Perhaps Sylow May Say Something" Paseman, 2018.11.26.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Yes, the case when $a_i$ is a prime (power) also is very interesting and is included in this question.

Comment: Then this question is relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850812/is-a-finite-group-always-a-element-wise-product-of-sylow-subgroups

Comment: Note that every group of order less than $12$ is definitely multifactorizable, and that $A_{4}$ is (up to isomorphism) the only group of order $12$ which is not multifactorizable. All groups of order less than $12$ and all groups of order $12$ other than (those isomorphic to) $A_{4}$ have a subgroup of order $d$ for each divisor $d$ of their order, and the argument used for nilpotent groups adapts to that situation.

Comment: As I wrote in a comment on a [related question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/316233/17064), you might be interested in googling the keyword "minimal logarithmic signature" for a related problem which has come under some scrutiny in cryptography and on which some progress has been made.

Comment: See https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927872.2021.1884254?journalCode=lagb20

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a Magma procedure to test whether $A_5$ is multifactorizable. A brute force search does not seem feasible, so I used the ideas in Taras Banakh's answer and in the comments.

Let $A_5 = ABCD$ with $|A|=2$, $|B|=3$, $|C|=5$, $|D|=2$. We may assume $A,B,C,D$ all contain the identity element. Then $A=\{e,a\}$ and $D=\{e,d\}$ where $a$ and $d$ distinct elements of order 2. Applying an automorphism of $A_5$ and using Taras's argument, we may reduce to the case $a=(1 2)(3 4)$ and $d=(2 3)(4 5)$.

I loop over all possible subsets $B$ of $A_5$ of size 3 containing $e$ such that $\# ABD = 12$ (there are 1248 such subsets). For each such $B$, I compute the list of all subsets of the form $ABcD$ with $c \in A_5$ which are disjoint from $ABD$ and are of size 12 (typically, there are about ten such subsets) and I test whether any of them add up to $A_5$. It turns out that there is no solution, so the group $A_5$ is not multifactorizable.

Comment: Thank you for this job! Now the question is resolved completely. But the problem of factorizability remains, nonetheless. Maybe it also has negative solution?

Comment: @TarasBanakh Your result about $A_4$ shows that that $a \times b \times c$-factorization does not hold in general, but I really have no clue about $a \times b$-factorization.

Comment: Why may we assume that all sets contain the identity element?

Comment: @LSpice We may replace the first set $A $ by $gA $ to ensure $e \in A $. Then we may replace $AB $ by $gAB=(gAg^{-1})(gB) $ to ensure $e \in B$ also, and so on with the other sets.

Answer (score 6):

Further to Gerhard Paseman's comment, it is true that finite $p$-groups are multifactorizable when $p$ is prime (and hence finite nilpotent groups are multifactorizable).
 Let $G$ be a $p$-group, and let each $a_{i}$ be a power of $p$ with $\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_{i} = |G|$. We show by double induction, first on $|G|$, then   on $n,$ that there are subsets
$A_{1},A_{2}, \ldots , A_{n}$ such that $A_{1}A_{2} \ldots A_{n} = G$ and that $A_{1}$ may be chosen to be a subgroup of $G$ of order $a_{1}.$

If $n = 1,$ we may take $A_{1} = G,$ so suppose that $n > 1.$ If $n =2,$ take $A_{1}$ to be a subgroup of $G$ of order $a_{1}$ and take $A_{2}$ to be a right transversal to $A_{1}$ in $G.$

Suppose then that $n > 2$ and the result is established for $n-1$ (and for $p$-groups of order less than $|G|)$.

Then $G$ has a subgroup $H$ of order $a_{1}a_{2},$ and there are subsets 
$A_{3},A_{4}, \ldots, A_{n}$ (with each $A_{i}$ of size $a_{i})$ such that 
$G = HA_{3} \ldots A_{n}.$

Since $n >2$, we have $a_{1}a_{2} < |G|$ and $|H| < |G|$. By induction ( or the case $n = 2$), $H$ has a subgroup $A_{1}$ of order $a_{1}$ and there is a subset $A_{2}$ of size $a_{2}$ of $H$ such that $A_{1}A_{2} = H.$

Then $G = A_{1} \ldots A_{n}$ with $A_{1}$ a subgroup of $G$ of order $a_{1}$ and each $A_{i}$  subset of $G$ of size  $a_{i}$ for $i > 1.$

Comment: In fact, one can find subsets $A_{1},\ldots,A_{n}$ ( each $A_{i}$ of size $a_{i}$) such that each ``partial product" $A_{1}.\ldots A_{i}$ is a subgroup for $1 \leq i \leq n$ by a slight variant of this argument ( for $G$ a finite $p$-group of order $a_{1}\ldots a_{n}$).

Answer (score 5):

I've just discovered that the alternating group $A_4$ is not multifactorizable. Namely, it can not be written as the product $A_4=ABC$ of subsets $A,B,C\subset A_4$ of cardinality $|A|=2$, $|B|=3$, and $|C|=2$.

The argument is as follows. To derive a contradiction, assume that $A_4=ABC$ for some subsets $A,B,C\subset A_4$ of cardinality $|A|=2$, $|B|=3$, $|C|=2$. Observe that for any $a\in A$, $b\in B$ and $c\in C$ the equality $ABC=A_4$ implies that $$(b^{-1}a^{-1}Ab)(b^{-1}B)(Cc^{-1})=b^{-1}a^{-1}ABCc^{-1}=A_4,$$ so we can replace the sets $A,B,C$ by the sets $b^{-1}a^{-1}Ab$, $b^{-1}B$, $Cc^{-1}$ and assume that the sets $A,B,C$ contain the neutral element $e$ of $A_4$.

Then $A=\{e,a\}$ and $C=\{e,c\}$ for some $a,c\in A_4$.

We claim that $a^2=e$. Assuming that $a^2\ne e$, we would conclude that $a^3=e$. 
Since the sets $BC$ and $aBC\ni a$ are disjoint, $a\notin BC$. Then $a^2\in ABC=BC\cup aBC$ implies $a^2\in BC$ and hence $e=a^3\in aBC$, which is not possible as the sets $aBC$ and $eBC\ni e$ are disjoint.
This contradiction shows that $a^2=e$. By analogy we can prove that $c^2=e$.

Since the sets $B\ni e$ and $aBc\ni ac$ are disjoint, $a\ne c$. Then $a,c,ac$ are the unique elements of order 2 in $A_4$.

Since the sets $B$, $aB\ni a$, $Bc\ni c$ and $aBc\ni ac$ are pairwise disjoint, the set $B$ contains no elements of order 2.

Fix any element $b\in B$ (or order 3). The group $A_4$ can be thought as the group of orientation-preserving isometries of a regular tetrahedron. Selecting a suitable enumeration of the vertices of the tetrahedron, we can assume that $a$ is the permutation $(12)(34)$ and $b$ is the cycle $(123)$. It is easy to check that $b^{-1}ab^{-1}=aba$.

One can check that $\{c,ac\}=\{bab^{-1},b^{-1}ab\}$ and $A_4\setminus\{e,a,c,ac\}=\{b,b^{-1},ab,ba,aba,ab^{-1},bab,b^{-1}a\}$.

It follows that $c=bab^{-1}$. Otherwise $c=b^{-1}ab$ and then the set 
$aBc\ni abb^{-1}ab=b$ is not disjoint with $B$.

Let $b'$ be the unique point of the set $B\setminus\{e,b\}$. Taking into account that the set $B$ is disjoint with $aB\cup Bc\cup aBc$, we conclude that $b'\notin\{b,ab,bc,abc\}=\{b,ab,b^{-1}ab^{-1},ab^{-1}ab^{-1}\}=\{b,ab,aba,ba\}$ and hence $b'\in\{b^{-1},ab^{-1},bab,b^{-1}a\}$.

If $b'=b^{-1}$, then $ab'c=ab^{-1}bab^{-1}=b^{-1}=b'$.

If $b'=ab^{-1}$, then $ab'c=ab^{-1}bab^{-1}=ab^{-1}=b'$.

If $b'=bab$, then $ab'c=ababbab^{-1}=abab^{-1}ab^{-1}=abaaba=ab^{-1}a=ab^{-1}ab^{-1}b=aabab=bab=b'$.

If $b'=b^{-1}a$, then $ab'c=ab^{-1}abab^{-1}=ab^{-1}ab^{-1}b^2ab^{-1}=aabab^{-1}ab^{-1}=baaba=b^{-1}a=b'$.

In all cases, we get $ab'c=b'$, which is not possible as the sets $aBc$ and $B$ are disjoint. This contradiction completes the proof.

> **Conclusion.** Since the group $A_4$ is solvable, it answers negatively  Problem 2 and (partly) Problem 1.

It remains find a finite simple group which is not multifactorizable.

Comment: For $A_4$, the maximum order for $|ABC|$ is $10$. Other groups of order $12$ are multifactorizable. Order $12$ is small enough so you can also check this quickly with a computer.

Comment: @spin What about $A_5$? Is it $2{\times}15{\times}2$ factorizable? Can this be checked by computer?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe a naive computer search is not feasible for $A_5$. For all subsets $A$ and $C$ of $A_5$ containing the identity with $|A| = |C| = 2$, I tried a small amount (around 10000) of random subsets $B$ with $|B| = 15$. The maximum value I could find for $|ABC|$ was $58$.

Comment: @TarasBanakh The same reasoning as in your argument shows that if $A_5=ABC$ with $A=\{e,a\}$ then $a^n \in BC$ (resp. $aBC$) if $n$ is even (resp. odd). Since the possible orders of $a$ are $2,3,5$, this implies that $a$ has order 2.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Thank you for this comments. Then $a$ and $c$ have order 2.  The number of elements of order 2 in $A_5$ equals 15. So the brute force algorithm will require considering $15\times 14\times\binom{57}{15}=1\,615\,875\,386\,202\,000\approx 1.6×10^{15}$ cases, which is accessible for modern (even laptop) computers. Maybe some information (restricting the search) can be derived also for the set $B$?

Comment: The elements $a,c$ cannot belong to a subgroup of $A_5$, which is isomorphic to $A_4$ as in this case $A_4=a(B\cap A_4)c$, so $|B\cap A_4|>3$ and the multiplication map $A\times B\times C\to A_5$ is not injective. So, the brute force can be improved to considering $12\times\binom{56}{14}=69 656 783 565 600\approx 6.9\times 10^{13}$ cases. Here we also use that all elements of order 2 are conjugated in $A_5$.

Comment: In fact we can fix the element $a$ and assume that it coinicides with the permutation $(12)(34)$. Since $a,c$ cannot belong to a subgroup isomorphic to $A_4$, the permutation $c$ should move the number $5$. So we can assume that $c$ is either $(12)(45)$ or $(23)(45)$. In the first case the elements $a,c$ generate a subgroup $H$ of order 6, which is not possible as $H=A(B\cap H)B$ and $6$ is not divided by 4. Consequently, $c$ can be identified with the permutation $(23)(45)$. This decreases the number of cases in the brute force algorithm to $\binom{56}{14}=5\,804\,731\,963\,800$ cases.

Comment: To make another improvement in the brute force algorithm, we should calculate the number (or better the structure) of the set $\{b\in A_4:abc=b\}$ where $a=(12)(34)$ and $c=(23)(45)$. Could anyone with access to GAP to find this set? Thank you!

Comment: @TarasBanakh The elements $b$ of $A_5$ satisfying $abc=b$ are $(15)(24),(12345),(14325),(135)$. Why can we discard $c=(13)(45)$?

Comment: Also, it would be easier to first show $A_5$ is not $2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 2$ factorizable.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Thank you! We can discard $c=(13)(45)$ because the pairs $a=(12)(34)$, $c=(23)(45)$ and $a=(12)(34)$, $c=(13)(45)$ can be mapped one to the other by an automorphism of $A_4$ (induced by the permutation $(12)$).

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault In order to prove that $A_5$ is (or is not) $2{\times}3{\times}5{\times}2$-factorizable, the brute force algorithm will require considering $\binom{52}{2}\binom{48}{4}=258\,013\,080$ or even better $\binom{52}{4}\binom{40}{2}=211\,165\,500$ cases, which can be easily done by computer. Unfortunately, I have no time (and experience to write programs).