# Cyclic and prime factorizations of finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, additive-combinatorics

> A tuple $(A_1,\dots,A_n)$ of subsets of a finite group $G$ is called a *factorization* of $G$ if $G=A_1\cdots A_n$ and $|A_1|\cdots|A_n|=G$.

In Cryptology factorizations of groups are known as *logarithmic signatures*.

A factorization $(A_1,\dots,A_n)$ of a group $G$ is called

$\bullet$ *minimal* if for every $i\le n$ the cardinality $|A_i|$ is prime or equal to 4;

$\bullet$ *prime* if for every $i\le n$ the cardinality $|A_i|$ is prime;

$\bullet$ *cyclic* if for every $i\le n$ the set $A_i$ is *cyclic* in the sense that $A_i=\{a_i^k:0\le k<|A_i|\}$ for some $a_i\in A_i$;

$\bullet$ a *decomposition* if each set $A_i$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Since each group of prime cardinality is cyclic, each prime decomposition is cyclic.

It is easy to see that each cyclic set $A$ can be written as the product $A=A_1\cdots A_n$ of cyclic sets $A_1,\dots,A_n\subset A$ of prime cardinality with $|A|=|A_1|\cdots|A_n|$.

Consequently, for any finite group $G$ we have the implications:

> $G$ has a prime decomposition $\Rightarrow$ $G$ has a cyclic decomposition
> $\Rightarrow$ $G$ has a cyclic factorization $\Rightarrow$ $G$ has a prime factorization $\Rightarrow$ $G$ has a minimal factorization.

For any prime number $p$ and any $n>1$ the cyclic group $C_{p^n}$ has a cyclic decomposition (and hence has a prime factorization) but does not have a prime decomposition.

The 8-element group $Q_8=\{1,-1,i,-i,j,-j,k,-k\}$ of quaternion units has a cyclic factorization but does not have a cyclic decomposition.

For other 3 properties we have 3 (open?) problems:

> **Problem M.** Has every finite group $G$ a minimal factorization?
>
> **Problem P.** Has every finite group $G$ a prime factorization?
>
> **Problem C.** Has every finite group $G$ a cyclic factorization?

Problem M is well-known in Cryptography as the problem of existence of a minimal logarithmic signature. Minimal (and cyclic) logarithmic signatures [have been constructed](https://fau.digital.flvc.org/islandora/object/fau%3A3667/datastream/OBJ/view/existence_of_minimal_logarithmic_signatures_for_classical_groups.pdf) in many classical finite groups and also in [some sporadic simple groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.01162). By Theorem 2.1 in [the Ph.D.Thesis of Singhi](https://fau.digital.flvc.org/islandora/object/fau%3A3667/datastream/OBJ/view/existence_of_minimal_logarithmic_signatures_for_classical_groups.pdf), solvable groups and all alternating groups have cyclic factorizations. Moreover, by the proof of Proposition 7.1 in [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3573/89e3d079c0ffb30030b99e6ed0fa3d267a3e.pdf) of Magliveras, every alternating group $A_n$ has a cyclic decomposition.

Nonetheless, Problem M is known to be open.

I am interested in the status of Problems P and C.

> Have we a counterexample to Problem C?

What is the role of the number 4 in the definition of a minimal factorization?

> Is there any example of a finite group for which we know that a minimal factorization exists but a prime (or cyclic) factorization cannot be constructed?

Comment: Wasn't it you who just gave $A_4$ as a counterexample for this yesterday? . . .  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316262

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies No, $A_4$ is not a counterexample: $A_4$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $C_2\times C_2$ and hence admits a decomposition $A_4=ABC$ with $|A|=|B|=2$ and $|C|=3$. What I proved yesterday, is that $A_4$ cannot be written as $A_4=ABC$ with $|A|=2$, $|B|=3$ and $|C|=2$.

Comment: The number $2$ is an exception in group theory, and in many cases (including p-groups), usually $4$ (say elements of order $4$) is used instead of $2$.

Comment: Conjecture 1' is true for solvable groups. In general, if Conjecture 1' is not true for a group G, then G is not the product of its Sylow subgroups. However, not every group is the product of its Sylow subgroups. A counterexample is $A_6$. Here, by the product of Sylow subgroup, it means the product of Sylow $p_i$-subgroups with $p_i$ being the distinct prime divisors of $|G|$.

Comment: @M.FarrokhiD.G. I have rewrote the problem. Now Conjecture 1' corresponds to Problems P and C. So, your observation about solvable groups can be written as the existnce of a cyclic factorization for any solvable group.

Comment: Note that $A_6$ satisfies Conjecture 1' as $A_5$ is the product of its Sylow subgroups and $A_6=A_5\cdot\{1,(1\ 2\ 6)\}\cdot\{1,\ (1\ 5)(2\ 6),(1\ 3)(4\ 6)\}$.

Comment: @M.FarrokhiD.G. The existence of cyclic (and prime) factorizations of solvable and alternating groups has been proved in Theorem 2.1 of the Ph.D.Thesis of Singhi.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, for each of Problems M/P/C the class of finite groups having such a factorization is closed under extensions.  In that case it's clear that such factorizations exist for soluble groups, and Problems M/P/C are really questions about nonabelian finite simple groups.

Comment: @ColinReid You are right. This is a question about finite simple groups. I admit that question D can have a negative answer for some solvable group, but cannot find a counterexample.

Comment: @ColinReid I have just realized that the quaterion group $Q_8$ admits no cyclic decomposition. So, only problems about factorizations remain open...