# Finite groups containing no subgroups of a given order or index

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

The classical Lagrange's Theorem says that the order of any subgroup of a finite group divides the order of the group. For abelian groups this theorem can be completed by the following simple fact: *Abelian groups contain subgroups of any order that divides the order of the group*. For non-abelian groups this is not true: the alternating group $A_4$ has cardinality 12 but contains no subgroup of cardinality 6; the alternating group $A_5$ has order 60 but contains no subgroup of order 30. On the other hand, these alternating groups contain subgroups of index 6 and 30, respectively.

> **Problem.** Is there a finite group $G$ and a divisor $d$ of $|G|$ such that $G$ contains no subgroup of order or index, equal to $d$? Is there such a group $G$ among finite simple groups?

Comment: $PSL_2(13)$ has order $21\times 52=1092$. According to Corollary 2.2 in https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/o.h.king/KingBCC05.pdf, its maximal subgroups have order $12$, $14$ and $78$. Hence it has no subgroup of order or index $21$ (i.e. order $21$ or $52$), which can certainly be checked by hand. (Note that $A_9$ has cardinal $181440$.)

Comment: $PSL_2(11)$ has order $15\times 44=660$. Using the same reference, its maximal subgroups have order $12,55,60$, those of order $60$ being alternating groups and thus not having subgroups of order $15$. Hence $PSL_2(11)$ has no subgroup of order or index $15$. There are only 4 smaller nonabelian finite simple groups, of order $60$, $168$, $360$, $504$. The first 3 give no example.

Comment: A simple verification by GAP shows that the only non-abelian simple groups of orders less than $1,000,000$ which do not satisfy the problem are $A_5$, $A_6$, $PSL(3,2)$, and $PSL(3,3)$.

Comment: @M.FarrokhiD.G. What is the smallest possible cardinality of a group satisfying the problem?

Comment: @TarasBanakh the previous 2 comments gave enough information to answer this question: it's 504. Namely $SL_2(8)$. It has order $21\times 24$ and its maximal subgroups have order $14$, $18$, $56$, $6$.

Comment: I have found that a similar question has been already asked at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143229/a-question-about-finite-groups-a-weak-version-of-the-converse-of-lagrange-theor

Comment: The smallest example is the $191$th small group $G$ of order $240$. Indeed, $G\cong(C_2\times C_2\times C_2\times C_2)\rtimes C_{15}$ is a Frobenius group.

Comment: In general, if $G=C_p^n\rtimes C_{p^n-1}$ is a Frobenius group, $m$ is divisor of $p^n-1$ and $1<k<n$ are such that neither $m|p^k-1$ nor $(p^n-1)|m(p^{n-k}-1)$, then $G$ has no subgroup of order or index $p^km$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The alternating group $A_{9}$ has no subgroup of order $35$ and no subgroup of index $35$. This can be checked from the Atlas ( or probably with GAP, etc). Note that if there were a subgroup of index $35,$ it would have to be maximal and its order would be $2^{6}.3^{4}$, so it is only necessary to check maximal subgroups, and there are none of that order.

Comment: ...or to check the products of Sylow 2- and 3-subgroups. (likewise, one may check that there is no product of 5- and 7-Sylow that is a subgroup.)

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov :Yes, there is no subgroup of order $35$ as an easy application of Sylow's Theorem shows that such a subgroup would have to be Abelian ( whereas $A_{9}$ has a self-centralizing Sylow $7$-subgroup). Also, in general, it is very rare for $A_{n}$ to have Hall subgroups which are not Sylow subgroups.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882859/groups-of-order-n2-that-have-no-subgroup-of-order-n) for some non-simple examples.