# A finite group that has no decomposition of given cardinality

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $a,b$ be two positive integer numbers. A group $G$ is called *$a{\times}b$-decomposable* if there are subsets $A,B\subset G$ of cardinality $|A|=a$ and $|B|=b$ such that $AB=G$ where $AB=\{xy:x\in A,\;y\in B\}$.

> I am looking for an example of a finite group $G$ which is not $a{\times}b$-decomposable for some numbers $a,b$ with $a\cdot b=|G|$.

**Remark.** It is easy to see that a group $G$ is $a{\times}b$-decomposable if $a\cdot b=|G|$ and $G$ contains a subgroup of order or index equal to $a$ or $b$. Consequently, any Abelian group $G$ is $a{\times}b$-decomposable for any numbers $a,b$ with $a\cdot b=|G|$.

According to the answer of Geoff Robinson to this [MO-problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316089/finite-groups-containing-no-subgroups-of-a-given-order-or-index) the alternating group $A_9$ contains no subgroups of order or index equal to 35.

> **Question 1.** Is the group $A_9$ $35{\times}5184$-decomposable?

By the comments of @YCor to the [same MO-problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316089/finite-groups-containing-no-subgroups-of-a-given-order-or-index),

$\bullet$ the group $PSL_2(11)$ has cardinality $|PSL_2(11)|=15\times 44$ but contains no subgroups of order or index 15;

$\bullet$ the group $PSL_2(13)$ has cardinality $|PSL_2(13)|=21\times 52$ but contains no subgroups of order or index 21.

> **Question 2.** Is the group $PSL_2(11)$ $15{\times}44$-decomposable?
>
> **Question 3.** Is the group $PSL_2(13)$ $21{\times}52$-decomposable?

Comment: @mathworker21 $A=\{0,1\}$, $B=\{0,2\}$. ($A,B$ are *subsets*, not necessarily subgroups.)

Comment: Related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177747/factorization-of-a-finite-group-by-two-subsets

Comment: Also: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155986/factor-subset-of-finite-group

Comment: Questions 1 and 2 have been answered in the affirmative, and the answer to Question 3 is also yes. There is a triple factorization ${\rm PSL}_2(13) = ABC$ into subgroups with $|A|=7$, $|B|=12$,  $|C|=13$, with $B \cong A_4$, and you can write $B$ as a product of subgroups of order $3$ and $4$ to get the required $21 \times 52$ factorization.

Comment: So, what is the intuitive expectation concerning the general problem? Is each group $a{\times}b$-decomposable?

Comment: I have no intuition about this at all, but I think it might be a very hard problem to resolve.

Comment: It is also easy to see that if $G$ admits two subgroups $H \subset K$ with $(K:H)$ equals to $a$ or $b$, then $G$ is $a \times b$-decomposable.

Comment: Decomposability makes sense for general Latin squares, but does not hold in general: there is a Latin square of order 9 with no $3 \times 3$ submatrix having distinct entries, see *Covers and partial transversals of Latin squares* https://doi.org/10.1007/s10623-018-0499-9 (discussion after Theorem 14).

Comment: It may be easier to look at an approximate version of this question: given $0 <a<1$ and $\varepsilon>0$, it it true that for a finite group $G$, there exist subsets $A,B$ with $|A| \ll |G|^{a+\varepsilon}$ and $|B| \ll |G|^{1-a+\varepsilon}$, such that $G=AB$?

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault The approximative version has been considered by Kozma and Lev, e.g. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01190111

Answer (score 5):

Answer to question 2: The group $G=\mathrm{PSL}_2(11)$ has an obvious subgroup $H$ of order 11 and (according to Magma) also a subgroup $H'$ of order 60 isomorphic to the alternating group $A_5$. Now $H'$ has a subgroup $K$ of order 4 (the Klein four-group). Letting $T$ be a transversal of $K$ in $H'$, we have $G = HH' = H(KT) = (HK)T$ so that $G$ is $15 \times 44$ decomposable.

Answer (score 5):

Question 1 can be solved in a similar manner to @FrançoisBrunault's answer.

Let $A_{i+1}=L_{i+1}A_i=A_iR_{i+1}$ with $|L_{i+1}|=|R_{i+1}|=i+1$. Then 
$A_9=A_7R_8R_9=L_7A_6R_8R_9=(L_7L_5)(A_4R_6R_8R_9)$.

Comment: It seems that your argument allows to prove that any alternating group $A_n$ is $a{\times}b$-decomposable for any $a,b$ with $ab=|A_n|$. Right?

Comment: At least, not directly. Check what happens with $A_{35}$ and $a$ being the product of maximal powers of 3 and 5 in $|A_{35}$.

Comment: It seems that the decomposability of the alternating groups $A_n$ can be proved by induction on n. Now I am trying to write down the proof (not very complicated).

Comment: Very interesting!

Comment: No,sorry, I was wrong, as not any finite group is a product of Sylow subgroups (one per prime)...

Comment: Unfortunately, my inductive "proof" of decomposability $A_n$ also failed.